# Edittext aftertextchange triggers multiple times when text changed programmatically

Tags: android

afterTextChanged is triggered for each character of the string if I change the contents of the EditText programmatically. Shouldn't editText.setText("abc") just trigger the listener once instead of 3 times?

Answer (score 2):

to detect if the user change the text or changed programmatically you can use
the setTag() function
for ex:

```
eddittext.setTag( "programmatically" );
eddittext.setText( "your text" );
eddittext.setTag(null);

//-----------------------------
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if( eddittext.getTag() == null )             
      // Value changed by user
else
      // changed programmatically
}
```

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to detect if a long string (>1) has been entered into the edittext box programmatically or if its a user just typing. It's difficult to determine the difference if the  afterTextChanged just returns a single character difference each time.